# Reading images of QR codes displayed in the browser

Tags: qr-code

I constantly come across websites that reference an Android application, and provide a QR code of the URL to download the application from the marketplace.  Those same sites very rarely provide the actual link to the application in any other form.

I am looking for way to read QR codes that are on the phone itself.  Ideally, I would like a method that utilizes the "share" functionality of the built in browser in such a way that I merely hold my finger down on an image of a QR code, select "share" from the resulting menu that comes up and select an app to send the image of the QR code to.

Are there any ways to do this or come close to the above functionality?

Comment: Interesting idea to use the "share" function to pass it an app that could read/interpret the QR code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this from the Browser itself using "[QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr)". Search for it and install it. After that:

- In the Browser, long-click the image and select "Save image"
- After downloaded, open image from notification bar
- Select Menu > Share > "Decode with QR Droid"

Answer (score 21):

[Barcode Generator / Reader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.sugree.barcodegen?install=web) is an app that reads and decodes QR codes from a file.

Also, you can bookmark this web based reader: [ZXing Decoder Online](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx), then when you come across a QR code, long-press on it, copy the image URL, then paste it into the linked page.