# How to utilize those Market QR codes?

Tags: google-play-store, barcode, qr-code

Once in a while I see a description of a program that is to be installed via Android market. It is often accompanied by a two-dimensional barcode looking like a QR code that I guess somehow contains a link to the right Market page and the process of using it should be very easy.

I've searched and the closest thing I found is [this question about reading QR Codes](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2581/1097) which makes me think it shouldn't be that hard and so I can't see whether that question is about the same usecase I'm asking about.

How exactly to make use of such barcodes? What's the way to proceed from the QR code on a web page to Market page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have installed the application "Barcode Scanner" from here https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android

To install an application, I open the "Barcode Scanner" application and hold the phone up to the barcode. It scans and decodes it automatically and then gives me the option to "open brower". I click on that and it eventually leads me to the Android market when I am given the option to install the application.

Comment: Also, scanning a QR Code, which contains a link to an app in the Market using Google Goggles usually opens your Market to the correct app. This would allow you to skip the web-page if you desire.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing a QR code on a web page that you are browsing with your phone, then generally there will also be a clickable link to the same place as the QR code points to.

If you are seeing a QR code on a web page on your browser on another device and want to follow it using your phone, you can install any one of a number of barcode scanning apps and then capture it using your camera; if the QR code encodes a market link, the scanner app should open it for you in the market.

I recommend [QR Droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=la.droid.qr&hl=en) for QR decoding myself, it's a very flexible little app that has tons of extra features (including generating your own QR codes that other phones can scan for things like contacts so you can easily share them, etc)