# Scan Barcode and QR code from the mobile screen itself

Tags: qr-code, barcode

How to scan barcodes from the mobile screen itself?

Edit on Mar 10, 2020: I am also looking to do the same for QR codes.

Comment: You could possibly try the solutions in [App that reads images of QR codes?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2581) I'm not sure if they work on other barcodes as well.

Comment: The recent [suggested edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/222277) is being discussed on the [meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2606/131553).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already described in the above comments, this would require taking a screenshot and saving it as an image file. Having done that, there are several barcode scanners available in the Play Store supporting "loading" of barcodes from image files, as e.g. [QR BARCODE SCANNER](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_progetto2003.SCAN). [QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr) also seems to be capable of what you're looking for:

> Scan QR codes from your camera, browser, SD card, or saved image

Comment: This is another one QR Scanner. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teacapps.barcodescanner

Answer (score -1):

I'm frequently using [Manatee Works](https://manateeworks.com/) 'Barcode Scanners' app for such a purpose. Here's the [Google Play Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manateeworks.barcodescanners) to the demonstration application.

The app supports a wide variety of 1D/2D codes, scans very fast, and is free. The only downside is that the option to manipulate the results is few, namely either copy or email, because it's a mere demonstration.