# How can I scan barcodes on webpages in Firefox for Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android, barcode

Using Firefox for Android, I occasionally find web pages containing barcode images (or photos containing barcodes) that I would like to scan.

I could save the image, switch to a barcode app, open and scan the image there, and probably end up relaunching the browser to see the result, but I'd *prefer* to long hold the image and launch the scanning app directly (with no save step required).

Is there an open source extension (Android app, Firefox add-on, Firefox app) that can achieve this? I've tried looking on the Firefox add-ons and apps marketplaces with no luck.

Example images:

- [f-droid.org](https://f-droid.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/fshotqr.png) (rendered image, imperfect QR code)
- [cryptojunky.com](http://cryptojunky.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/q1aR9Ee.jpg) (photo, imperfect QR code)
- [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Azteccodeexample.svg/200px-Azteccodeexample.svg.png) (rendered Aztec code)

Comment: This might be a duplicate: [App that reads images of QR codes?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2581)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox for android you can long press the image and select share. From there just choose "decode QR code".
Make sure you first install the program "QR droid". 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr